Salesforce Connect - why is the OData 4.01 configuration so different from OData 4.0?
According to Oasis Org, OData 4.01 has some significant improvements such as

Extended Query Language
Simplified Syntax
Simplified Payloads
Easier partial adoption of OData in existing REST APIs

After setting up the External Data Store in Salesforce, I noticed that OData 4.01 has far fewer options, including:

High Data Volume
Request Row Counts
Server Driven Pagination
Compress Requests
Format
Special Compatibility

(The above is true as of Winter '25)
Additionally, 4.01 asks for a Named Credential and OData 4.0 instead has its own Authentication.
I want to build my own OData source, and want to know which features are available in OData 4.0 that are not available in the 4.01 adapter?
For example, I wouldn't build or test High Data Volume in Salesforce with the 4.01 adapter because it is (apparently) not supported in the current version.



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I rewrote the question to be more specific about the outcome desired

The Microsoft documentation about OData defines the difference between the two as:

OData 4.01 is highly compatible, incremental release over OData 4.0. A compliant 4.01 OData Service fully supports OData 4.0 clients. New OData 4.01 query features and simplified syntax can be supported as compatible extensions to OData 4.0 syntax. Content negotiation is facilitated through the ODataVersion header to ensure OData 4.0 clients don't receive unexpected constructs in response payloads.

Note: the highlight was mine to show that the 4.01 OData connector should, in theory, support whatever the 4.0 was doing.
So, by deduction, the whole setup might not be needed anymore and instead is all handled automatically by the Salesforce platform for you, much like it handles OAuth 2.0 token refresh when using that protocol when connecting to services using that protocol.
The Salesforce documentation doesn't say much about the difference between the two, so all I've said above is inferred.

I was also thinking the same, but 'High Data Volume' is a significant configuration (for example) that has to be specified because Salesforce behaves very differently.

Might be a good idea to raise a case with Salesforce to ask this (and to update their documentation on it too, while at it).
